# Having trouble getting rails 5.1.5 to submit materialize css dropdown value via capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I am having some difficult getting a materialize css dropdown to submit its value when "selected". I use quotes because I am not sure if I am actually selecting the value properly.

I am working with:

```
rails 5.1.5
capybara 2.18.0
rspec-rails 3.6.0
```

My current feature spec is as follows:

```
require 'rails_helper'

feature 'organization management', js: true do
  let(:organization) {create :organization}

  scenario 'a user can view an organization they created' do
    set_session organization.user

    visit root_path

    within '.nav-wrapper' do
      click_link 'Organizations'
      click_link 'New Organization'
    end

    expect(current_path).to eq new_organization_path

    fill_in 'organization[name]', with: Faker::Company.name
    fill_in 'organization[address1]', with: Faker::Address.street_address
    fill_in 'organization[city]', with: Faker::Address.city

    # Chose to use JS because I couldn't get select helper to work
    evaluate_script("$('input.select-dropdown').val('Maryland');")

    fill_in 'organization[zipcode]', with: Faker::Address.zip
    fill_in_trix_editor 'trix-editor', Faker::Lorem.paragraph

    click_button 'Create Organization'

    expect(current_path).to eq organization_path(Organization.last)

  end
end
```

Once the create button is clicked, I see the state value is not submitted:

```
Started POST "/organizations" for ::1 at 2018-05-02 13:49:13 -0400
Processing by OrganizationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "organization"=>{"name"=>"Spinka, Kautzer and Strosin", "address1"=>"4611 Mueller Ports", "address2"=>"", "city"=>"Madelynnland", "state"=>"", "zipcode"=>"19244-0263", "description"=>"<div>Earum saepe esse commodi. Autem nisi quis quia sed. Molestiae accusantium quaerat. Rerum quod sapiente dolorem laborum enim et autem.</div>"}, "commit"=>"Create Organization"}
```

I have ran through this in the browser myself (outside of the tests) and things work fine.

I have no idea why the select helper wasn't working for me at all.

The only difference I noticed from me manually testing this and rspec testing it is the label didn't move when selecting a value during the test. The value that was selected and the label of the dropbox overlapped.

When I manually selected a value, the label moved like normal.

Any thoughts or ideas on how I can get things working in the feature test would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`select` doesn't work because the user isn't interacting with an actual HTML <select> element, they're're interacting with a JS widget which then most likely sets the actual (hidden) form field.  Rather than using `evaluate_script`, which won't generate the events the widget needs to copy the selected value to the original HTML select (or know the value has been changed), you need to replicate the actions a user would perform. Without seeing the actual HTML it's impossible to give exactly what you'd need to do but it usually boils down to just clicking on the elements a user would actually click on, alongs the lines of

```
find('CSS selector of the dropdown trigger').click # make the dropdown widget show
find('li', text: 'Maryland').click # click on the desired selection in the dropdown widget
```

Also note you should never use `eq` with current_path/url since it will lead to flaky tests, instead you should be using the `have_current_path` matcher provided by Capybara

```
expect(page).to have_current_path(organization_path(Organization.last))
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I should have thought to try the step by step approach as you suggested. I appreciate you taking the time to further explain things and share a new piece of code I was unaware of.